# pass variable url laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

why always Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

> 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8882:
>
> in compiled.php line 8882
>       at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8206
>       at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8134
>       at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8130

and this is my route:

```
Route::get('/reportpeta/{filterperiode}','PetaReportController@getProvinsi');
```

**view.blade**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => url('/reportpeta/'),'method' => 'get')) }}
    ....
{{!! Form::close() !!}}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getProvinsi($filterperiode){
.......
}
```

and this is problem because calling

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => url('/reportpeta/'),'method' => 'get')) }}
```

please tell me how to call url correctly

Answer (score 1):

**filterperiode** is required parameter

```
Route::get('/reportpeta/{filterperiode}','PetaReportController@getProvinsi');
```

You can make it optional

```
Route::get('/reportpeta/{filterperiode?}','PetaReportController@getProvinsi');
```

Don't miss to make function parameter optional

```
public function getProvinsi($filterperiode = null)
```

According to @Ijas Ameenudeen Comment

Comment: thanks for an answer but still is Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8882:

    in compiled.php line 8882
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8206
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8134
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8130
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2472

Comment: Try 
php artisan route:list
from cmd to get all routes

Comment: i have been php artisan route:list and result route in list

Comment: @iipmuhamadikbal have you tried second code in above answer ?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal , maybe im wrong when calling in views.blade 

{{ Form::open(array('url' => url('/reportpeta/'),'method' => 'get')) }}
but i dont know how calling its true

Comment: @SagarGautam , yes have done and result still error thats

Comment: @iipmuhamadikbal No problem with opening form as i see in the docs https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#opening-a-form

Comment: @iipmuhamadikbal everything looks fine. Can you add all content of web.php and form blade

Comment: @MahmoudGamal , sorry have been try second code in above answer . Now error is Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ErrorException in PetaReportController.php line 62: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PetaReportController::getProvinsi()

    in PetaReportController.php line 62
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PetaReportController::getProvinsi()', '/home/tru3d3v/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/PetaReportController.php', '62', array()) in PetaReportController.php line 62
    at PetaReportController->getProvinsi()

Comment: make the param optional in the controller method. `public function getProvinsi($filterperiode = null){
`

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen 
{{ Form::open(array('url' => url('/reportpeta/'),'method' => 'get')) }}
                       <div class="" id="filter">
                                  <div class='form-group'> 
                                   {!! Form::select('filterperiode',[],null,['class'=>'form-control periodeSearch']) !!}
                                  </div>
                          </div>                  
                        
                    </div><
                    <div class="box-footer">

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen                      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Proses</button>
                      {!! Form::close() !!}

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen I have done make the param optional in the controller method. public function getProvinsi($filterperiode = null), when running program result is []

Comment: It depends on your business logic. If the issue is fixed, you can accept the answer.